# Questions about word embedding(word2vec)

Tags: neural-network, word2vec, word-embedding

I am trying to understand word2vec(word embedding) architecture, and I have few questions about it:

- first, why is word2vec model considered a log-linear model? Is it because it uses a soft max at output layer?
- second, why does word2vec remove hidden layer? Is it just because of computational complexity?
- third, why does word2vec not use activation function? (as compared to NNLM(Neural Network Language Model).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> first, why word2vec model is log-linear model? because it uses a soft max at output layer?

Exactly, softmax is a log-linear classification model. The intent is to obtain values at the output that can be considered a posterior probability distribution

> second, why word2vec removes hidden layer? it just because of
>   computational complexity?
>   third, why word2ved don't use activation function? compare for
>   NNLM(Neural Network Language Model).

I think your second and third question are linked in the sense that an extra hidden layer and an activation function would make the model more complex than necessary. Note that while no activation is explicitly formulated, we could consider it to be a linear classification function. It appears that the dependencies that the word2vec models try to model can be achieved with a linear relation between the input words.

Adding a non-linear activation function allows the neural network to map more complex functions, which could in turn lead to fit the input onto something more complex that doesn't retain the dependencies word2vec seeks.

Also note that linear outputs don't saturate which facilitates gradient-based learning.

Comment: What does this mean?
`...., which could in turn lead to fit the input onto something more complex that doesn't retain the dependencies word2vec seeks.`

Comment: I meant that it might overfit on any (random) non-linear relations it might find.